# `sudo apt autoremove` suggests removing large package

Tags: server, apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I recently ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install` in Ubuntu server, and APT suggested running `sudo apt autoremove`. When I run that command, it warns me:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31 linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-62
  linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 9 to remove and 51 not upgraded.
```

These packages are very big, over 400mb, and I think it's a kind of kernel version. Is okay to confirm deleting those packages?

Comment: It's normal if you have 3-4 kernel installed. This kernel is probably an old kernel which you never use. However if you curious you can type `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` and see other linux kernels. It's better idea to have at least 2 kernel.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`autoremove` is smart. It removes old kernel versions along with all their baggage, leaving the current kernel and one spare. It also runs `update-grub` to clean the bootloader menu. You should proceed without trepidation :)

However, before running it, you can see your current kernel version with `uname -r`, then you can see for sure `autoremove` isn't going to delete your running kernel or any of its files.

You can also do `ls /boot` to see the kernels you have there and compare with what `autoremove` is going to do.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very clear and simple to understand :)

Comment: There is a bug and `sudo apt autoremove` probably will remove your current and running kernel.

Comment: @BrunoKarklis do you have a link to further information about this bug?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1615381
Just happened to me minutes ago and had to recover the lost kernel by usb live.

Comment: @BrunoKarklis Thanks! Since the kernel is in RAM, you can normally reinstall the running kernel after removing it by running the command `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)` (I have tested this).

Comment: but... if you reboot or the system simple crash before remember to reinstall the kernel... this command with this bug is the same to play with fire.

Comment: Thanks guys, any idea how long this autoremove should take? My cursor has been blinking for 15 minutes without any logs or outputs... I am running this on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance. NVM the server was just disconnected. I reran without issues.